# How to rollback a jquery buttonset

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a buttonset, with a change event. On change, to event calls an ajax post to save the value. In case of error, I want the buttonset to be set back to its initial state.

So I keep the initial state into a variable on page load (intital).
If the ajax call fails, in the "error" function, I use  'initial'  to check corresponding button.

The issue is that the graphical buttonset doens't get back to its initial value. 
Worse, when I do an alert of the two buttons, I see the checked attr is correctly set, but not reflected on screen.

Help appreciated, because I googled a lot about this:-(

the JS code:

```
//keep initial buttonset checked value
var intial = $( '#radio :checked');

//on buttonset change, do a ajax post, and in case of failure, set original value back
$( "#radio" ).buttonset().change(function(){
    $.post("/to/somewhere",{showList:'show', id:123})
        .error(function(){
            if (intial.val() == "show"){
                $('#visibleYes').attr("checked", true);
            } 
            else {
                $('#visibleNo').attr("checked", true);
            }
        })                
    })
});
```

the html code

```
<div id="radio">
   <input class="yesNoRadio" type="radio" id="visibleYes" name="visible" value="show" checked="checked"/><label for="visibleYes">Show</label>
   <input class="yesNoRadio" type="radio" id="visibleNo"  name="visible" value="hide" /><label for="visibleNo">Hide</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Just so you know, your JavaScript is actually jQuery.

Comment: @MattD, jQuery is Javascript. It's only a library, not a language.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I know that, but if he's writing this thinking it's JavaScript when it's jQuery, and he isn't referencing a jQuery library, then anything anyone does to fix his code won't work. Probably should have noted that in my initial comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should [refresh](http://api.jqueryui.com/button/#method-refresh) the button widgets after updating the `checked` attributes of the augmented elements:

```
$(intial.val() == "show" ? "#visibleYes" : "#visibleNo")
    .prop("checked", true).button("refresh");
```

Note that I used [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/), which is recommended with boolean properties like `checked`.

Comment: It works... You saved my day:-) I was actually struglling with the buttonset, when I would have to do as you did, directly on the button. Thanks a lot

Comment: @xavier If this is the solution you used, you should mark it as answered.